# Adding an INDEX to a CTE

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

Can I add an INDEX to a Common Table Expression (CTE)?

Comment: It might be sort of possible with some messing around with plan guides. [This article](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/28/generating-xml-in-subqueries/) by [Quassnoi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) shows how to use a plan guide to get the results of a CTE cached by adding an EagerSpool to the plan. This builds a temporary index over them in tempdb.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.

A CTE is a temporary, "inline" view - you cannot add an index to such a construct.

If you need an index, create a regular view with the SELECT of your CTE, and make it an indexed view (by adding a clustered index to the view). You'll need to obey a set of rules outlined here: [Creating an Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

Comment: For me, Indexed view took 18 seconds first try, then 16 seconds, then 14 seconds third try. CTE took 16 seconds first try. I'll stick with CTE. BTW, for me indexed table (used temporarily) was the best getting down to 10 seconds overall.

Comment: You can create indexes on the underlying tables and it will be used by the CTE if necessary. _Before_ you start talking about indexed views, make sure your underlying tables are indexed properly. In my opinion, indexed views are usually unecessary.

Answer (score 92):

I have had the same requirement.  Indexes can not be added to a CTE.  However, in the CTE select adding an **ORDER BY** clause on the joined fields reduced the execution time from 20 minutes or more to under 10 seconds.

(You need to also ADD SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT to allow an ORDER BY in a CTE select.)

*[edit to add paraphrased quote from a comment below]:*
If you have DISTINCT in the CTE then TOP 100 PERCENT doesn't work. This cheater method is always available: without needing TOP at all in the select, alter the ORDER BY statement to read:
ORDER BY [Blah] OFFSET 0 ROWS

Comment: Where'd you learn such voodoo?  It has a remarkable effect on a long-running query we had.  Top 100000 works better than Top 100 PERCENT.  I'm going to start digging into the query analyzer to see what's going on.  Thanks!

Comment: That is very interesting and good to know.   I changed my query from top 1000000 to top 100 PERCENT.   I will change it back.    I came across  post on MSDN with this hint when trying to index a CTE for perforance.

Comment: TOP 100 PERCENT might use the number of estimated records to return. TOP 1000000 might think that there will be more and reserve more memory to the execution so that there are no Sort Warnings and spills to TempDB.

Comment: When you say in the CTE select, do you mean the select that's creating the CTE, or the select that's using the CTE?

Comment: The select creating the CTE.  That orders the data in the CTE for efficient use in the subsequent query.

Comment: I think... based on what you're trying to achieve you need to make another view out of your CTE statement and reference it that way.

Comment: i always love to know these technique, can you set up a example to prove that thanx

Comment: Hard to put an example up that will be meaningful to you, as you will need to execute against substantial data set to see the value.  I will look for the query that gave me this benefit and document in more detail the results and performance improvement for you in the next few days.

Comment: @BlackjacketMack: "voodoo".  In retrospect, the error message for using ORDER BY in a CTE is pretty clear: 'The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.'  But hats off to Richard for his answer.  I needed DISTINCT in my CTE so TOP 100 PERCENT didn't work.  This cheater method is always available: ORDER BY [Blah] OFFSET 0 ROWS

Comment: In my situation, this made it 4 seconds slower (19seconds vs 16 seconds)

Comment: This greatly improved the performance of my CTE!  Thanks
But... Why did it improve the performance so much??

Comment: Incredible tip. I guess the effect is kind of the same as indexing, if you ORDER BY the column that you JOIN to the CTE on, the optimizer knows that it's ordered and treats it like an indexed column.

Comment: WAIT this is cargo cult stuff. You don't just add magic keywords to make your query run faster. You need to analyse the query plan and work out what's different.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot index a CTE, but the approach is that the CTE can make use of the underlying indexes.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT myname, SUM(Qty) FROM t GROUP BY myname
)
SELECT *
FROM t a JOIN cte b ON a.myname=b.myname
```

In the above query, `a JOIN b` cannot make use of an index on `t.myname` because of the `GROUP BY`.

On the other hand,

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT myname, SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY myname) AS SumQty, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY myname ORDER BY myname, Qty) AS n
)
SELECT * FROM t a JOIN cte b ON a.myname=b.myname AND b.n=1
```

In the latter query, `a JOIN b` can make use of an index on `t.myname`.

Comment: The query planner will find the fastest way to do it. It's quite possible the two queries have an identical query plan

Answer (score 2):

Another technique is to insert into a temp table instead of using a CTE
You can then add an index to the temp table

I reduced a 9min query to a 3 sec query by doing this.

Some may be religiously opposed to temp tables.

for the rest of us trying to get things working... something to consider.

( I did try the top 100000 ... order by) I did not realize a time reduction.

Comment: I'm in the process of trying this right now, I ain't got no religion in this matter! It is a very complex CTE with multiple parts, so think I may need to break it into to different procedures, one to populate the tmp table and one to read from it in the second half. Glad to hear of your success.

Comment: @ckapilla  - i will say that if you fill a temp table in one sp and then try to process it in another, you could find you have built a monster that is hard to debug.  i have run into something similar  once and it was no fun trying to figure out why the results were not what we expected..  I dont know your particulars of course, but you may want to consider  keeping it all in one sp.

Comment: Yep good point - temp tables introduce concurrency issues - two people can't run the same query at the same time. This might be fine. For performance tuning I _always_ recommend analysing the query plan as the _first_ step. This might suggest some indexes, or temp table might legitimately be the only way to speed it up

Answer (score 2):

/* The Below construct reduced my query from 2 minutes to 4 seconds */

```
WITH First_cte AS(
    SELECT Field1, Field2, etc
    FROM etc
    ORDER BY Field1, Field2 OFFSET 0 ROWS
),
Second_cte AS(
    SELECT Field1, Field2, etc
    FROM etc
    ORDER BY Field1, Field2 OFFSET 0 ROWS
)
SELECT
    First_cte.Field1, First_cte.Field2, etc
    FROM First_cte
    INNER JOIN Second_cte
        ON Second_cte.Field1 = First_cte.Field1
        AND Second_cte.Field2 = First_cte.Field2
    WHERE Second_cte.Field3 <> First_cte.Field3`
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works? I've tried this solution for my Query and reduced the execution time from around 1:30 minutes to 4 seconds, but I'd like to understand the logic behind it.