# Order by issue in Common Table Expression

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am using Common Table Expression in stored procedure shown below I want to display the country name in ascending order

```
1   | India
2   | Bangladesh
3   | Srilanka
4   | Nepal
5   | Japan
```

The expression is as follows

```
WITH CTECountry as
(
SELECT 
   CountryID,
   CountryName 
FROM dbo.Country
ORDER BY CountryName ASC        
)
SELECT 
*
FROM CTECountry 
UNION SELECT '0','--Select--'
```

Comment: You should move the order by to the other select.

Comment: I want to use the order by inside the expression itself

Comment: @MathewPaul: that has no meaning

Comment: @gbn The reason is in some systems when I give the order by outside it takes '--Select--' as 'Select' and will display in between 'Nepal' and 'Srilanka' I want to display '--Select--' at the top only

Comment: Why in the end do you want to append '0','--Select--' when you should do this on your consumer?

Comment: @MathewPaul:  '--Select--' does not sort that way. The '--' means it can't

Comment: As @Adrian has said, wouldn't appending '--Select--' be a client-side concern?

Answer (score 5):

The ORDER BY applies to the whole UNION (which needs ALL in this case).

In any case, **only** outermost ORDER BY clauses are guaranteed to sort the results. Inner and intermediate ORDER BY clauses don't have any effect or generate errors except in certain cases.

```
WITH CTECountry as
(
SELECT 
   CountryID,
   CountryName 
FROM dbo.Country
)  
SELECT 
   CountryID,
   CountryName 
FROM CTECountry 
UNION ALL
SELECT '0','--Select--'
ORDER BY CountryName ASC   -- goes here
```

Edit, I suspect you want this after comment above

```
WITH CTECountry as
(
SELECT 
   CountryID,
   CountryName,
   1 AS SortOrder
FROM dbo.Country
UNION ALL
SELECT '0','--Select--', 2
)  
SELECT 
   CountryID,
   CountryName 
FROM 
   CTECountry
ORDER BY
   SortOrder, CountryName ASC
```

Comment: I cant use it outside need to put that inside the expression itself

Comment: @MathewPaul: well, you can't. See my 2nd query. Or update your question to explain what you really want...

Comment: @gbn Based on the comment "I want to display '--Select--' at the top only", I think you should switch your SortOrder values.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to GBN's answer, but slightly simpler:

```
WITH CTECountry as
(
SELECT 
   CountryID,
   CountryName 
FROM dbo.Country
)
SELECT 
*
FROM CTECountry 
UNION SELECT 0,'--Select--'
ORDER BY sign(CountryID) DESC, CountryName ASC
```

(Assumes CountryID is actually numeric, not a string)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by modifying the query to

> WITH CTECountry as
>   ( 
>      SELECT
>         ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
>         (
>       ORDER BY CountryName ASC
>         )AS Rownumber,
>         CountryID,
>         CountryName
>      FROM 
>         dbo.Country 
>      ORDER BY CountryName ASC
>   ) 
>   SELECT  * FROM CTECountry  UNION SELECT '0','--Select--'

Answer (score 1):

In the case of SQL SERVER, I have found there is another way to do this although it's imperfect. You add TOP 999999999999 to the CTE:

```
WITH CTECountry as
(
SELECT TOP 99999999999
   CountryID,
   CountryName 
FROM dbo.Country
ORDER BY CountryName ASC        
)
SELECT 
*
FROM CTECountry 
UNION SELECT '0','--Select--'
```

The number doesn't matter but you want it to be high enough that you will never realistically hit it. It's a bit hacky but if you ever need a quick workaround for one reason or another this'll do

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Arch answer you can do the following in sql server

```
 WITH CTECountry as
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
   CountryID,
   CountryName 
FROM dbo.Country
ORDER BY CountryName ASC        
)
SELECT 
*
FROM CTECountry 
UNION SELECT '0','--Select--'
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995958/adding-an-index-to-a-cte)