# Please explain the execution of this simple SQL query

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

DDL & DMLs for creating this table:

```
  Create table If Not Exists Delivery (delivery_id int, customer_id int, order_date date, customer_pref_delivery_date date);
Truncate table Delivery;
insert into Delivery (delivery_id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date) values ('1', '1', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-02');
insert into Delivery (delivery_id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date) values ('2', '2', '2019-08-02', '2019-08-02');
insert into Delivery (delivery_id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date) values ('3', '1', '2019-08-11', '2019-08-12');
insert into Delivery (delivery_id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date) values ('4', '3', '2019-08-24', '2019-08-24');
insert into Delivery (delivery_id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date) values ('5', '3', '2019-08-21', '2019-08-22');
insert into Delivery (delivery_id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date) values ('6', '2', '2019-08-11', '2019-08-13');
insert into Delivery (delivery_id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date) values ('7', '4', '2019-08-09', '2019-08-09');
```

[image]

I want to rearrange the rows of this table in ascending order of customer_id and for multiple rows of same customer_id ascending order of order_date.
For getting that I was writing query as:

```
with t1 as (select *
            from delivery
            order by customer_id, order_date),
t2 as (select * from t1 group by customer_id)
select * from t2;
```

and I was getting this table:
[image]

Here in **third row instead of 2019-08-24 I was expecting 2019-08-21**. Please explain what am I doing wrong in **THIS SOLUTION**? Please explain why rearrangement is not happening as per the CTE specified?

Comment: Can you provide the code for creating the table? Then I can use it to fiddle around and give you the solution

Comment: Ordering within a derived table or table expression is redundant; ordering is only guaranteed in the outer select if you apply and ordering criteria there; grouping without aggregation is incorrect.

Comment: @Stu  Can you please explain how ordering within a derived table becomes redundant, because as everything which is written in the subquery executes perfectly why is "ordering" not executing? and I don't see any contradiction in the chronology of execution of this SQL statement (That I thought might be the reason of getting incorrect result with my approach).

Comment: @ZEESHANAHMED an often misunderstood quality of sets; your set (the cte) has no inherant ordering, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969765/order-by-issue-in-common-table-expression) for example

Comment: I can't wrap my head around or find any syntactical reason why CTE has no inherent ordering even though I used order by clause in CTE t1, and how come group by in t2 is executing but order by in t1 is not?

Comment: "for multiple rows of same customer_id ascending order of order_date" disagrees with your desired output.  Rephrase to "for multiple rows of same customer_id show just the first byf order_date".  This a "groupwise-max" problem; follow the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optimizing Derived Tables, View References, and Common Table Expressions with Merging or Materialization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html#:%7E:text=The%20optimizer%20avoids%20materializing%20the,the%20result%20is%20never%20needed.) states:

> The optimizer propagates an ORDER BY clause in a derived table or view reference to the outer query block if these conditions are all true:
>
> - The outer query is not grouped or aggregated.
> - The outer query does not specify DISTINCT, HAVING, or ORDER BY.
> - The outer query has this derived table or view reference as the only source in the FROM clause.
>
> Otherwise, the optimizer ignores the ORDER BY clause.

Because `t1` is then being `grouped` in `t2`, `the optimizer ignores the ORDER BY clause`.

Your query, and that proposed by SickerDude43, are both [nondeterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html#:%7E:text=This%20causes%20MySQL%20to%20accept%20the%20preceding%20query.%20In%20this%20case%2C%20the%20server%20is%20free%20to%20choose%20any%20value%20from%20each%20group%2C%20so%20unless%20they%20are%20the%20same%2C%20the%20values%20chosen%20are%20nondeterministic%2C%20which%20is%20probably%20not%20what%20you%20want). They only return at all because ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled. All selected columns (and expressions) should either be in an aggregate function or functionally dependant on the GROUP BY clause.

You should read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Here are some typical solutions for [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+greatest-n-per-group):

```sql
-- greatest (or least) per group using aggregate subquery
-- this will return multiple rows for a customer_id if there are multiple orders on min_order_date
SELECT d.*
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS min_order_date
    FROM delivery
    GROUP BY customer_id
) d_min
JOIN delivery d
    ON d_min.customer_id = d.customer_id
    AND d_min.min_order_date = d.order_date;
```

```sql
-- greatest (or least) per group using correlated subquery
SELECT d1.*
FROM delivery d1
WHERE delivery_id = (
    SELECT delivery_id
    FROM delivery d2
    WHERE d1.customer_id = d2.customer_id
    ORDER BY customer_id, order_date, delivery_id
    LIMIT 1
);
```

```sql
-- greatest (or least) per group using ROW_NUMBER() window function (MySQL >= 8.0)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, delivery_id) AS rn
    FROM delivery
) d
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The aggregate and correlated subqueries will benefit from an index on `(customer_id, order_date)`.

Which one is fastest will depend on the distribution of your data. Give them a try.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/je3d-S8u).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @user1191247. I understand that the queries become nondeterministic when functionally independent columns are present in a query with group by clause (There can also be other reasons for a query to be nondeterministic). Stating reasons of inexecution of order by clause is greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is unnecessary complicated.

Just select the lowest value for the order date with the MIN() function.

```
select delivery_id, customer_id, MIN(order_date), 
customer_pref_delivery_date from delivery
group by customer_id
```

This should work.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a8a51/1

The reason why your solution doesn't work is explained in the comments.

Comment: This is a nonsense query which only returns at all because ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled. The delivery_id values do not correlate with the order_date values. All selected columns (or expressions) should either be in an aggregate function or functionally dependant on the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user1191247 yes, delivery_id column is irrelevant here and selected columns should either be aggregate or functionally dependant on group by clause (But even if selected columns are not agg. or functionally dependant then also group by a particular column works and worked here as in CTE t2).    Can you please explain what do you mean by "only_full_ group_by is disabled"?

Comment: @ZEESHANAHMED You should read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D9C1azYB)

Comment: @user1191247 While I wouldn't call it non-sense, I admit your solution is far better and mine is non-deterministic  - which is generally something you don't want.

Comment: Apologies. Indeed, nondeterministic was the word I was looking for. When I read it back 24hrs later it seemed a little harsh but comments can only be edited for a few minutes after being added.

Comment: @user1191247 No problem mate, you're just trying to help :) Have a nice day!