# Database Join Logic for finding exception member

Tags: sql, relational-database, inner-join

I have 3 table

```
User (UserID)
ROOM (RoomID, UserID)  ---the userID is the host
RoomMember (RMid, RoomID, UserID)  ---the UserID is the people inside the room
```

This is an example of 1 user host a room .
Then the Room member is those who inside the room.
now, i want to invite more member that not within the room.
how do I write a query to find those who not in the room AND also not a Host of the room.

for SQL asp.net C#  query
I not sure how to do this using inner Join .

Comment: what do you mean with "asp.net c# query"??
Using linq? or plain sql?

Comment: Sorry, Just plain sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of ways to do this, but the most simple does not even require an `INNER JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @RoomID INT = 101 -- or whatever room
SELECT * FROM [User]
WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM ROOM WHERE RoomID = @RoomID)
AND UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM RoomMember WHERE RoomID = @RoomID)
```

This works by excluding the user who reserved the room, and also excluding all users already a member of the room.

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46143/6

You can take this a step further and first build up the list of "excluded" members in a CTE, and then just doing a single `NOT IN`:

```
DECLARE @RoomID INT = 101 -- or whatever room
;WITH RoomUsers
AS
(
    SELECT UserId FROM ROOM WHERE RoomID = @RoomID
    UNION
    SELECT UserId FROM RoomMember WHERE RoomID = @RoomID
)
SELECT * FROM [User]
WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT userId FROM RoomUsers)
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46143/4/0

Comment: Does this use possible indizes of `ROOM` and `RoomMember`?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - Why wouldn't it? (I assume Indizes = Indexes)

Comment: because you are doing a `UNION` and building up a CTE ... an execution plan would be interesting ;) I am not sure though, that is why I've asked. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995958/adding-an-index-to-a-cte and http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117)