# How to Create index for cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query:

```
With Cte as (some code)

Select * 
from Cte
order by id
```

Can I create a index for this cte?

I'm using ms SQL Server 2005

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot add index to cte.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995958/adding-an-index-to-a-cte

Comment: You can't, CTE is like a dynamic view inside the statement. You probably need to create a temporary table and index that.

Comment: CTE doesn't create any temporary table or something that can be indexed. it will use the indexes of the table during its execution.

Comment: But, you can create index for the table inside the code of the cte

Answer (score 2):

Like said above Indexes cannot be added to a CTE.

However, in the CTE select adding an ORDER BY clause on the joined fields can reduce the execution time.

You need to also ADD SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT to allow an ORDER BY in a CTE select.

Comment: SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT is not psql command

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a materialized/indexed view as the underlyer instead of a CTE. It will require you to create the DDL in advance, but if query performance is important, it might be a help.
Also, keep in mind that you will not be able to change the underlying tables because of the schemabinding requirement.