# Switching a case statement to a constant greatly slows query

Tags: sql-server, performance, case

I have run into an issue with SQL Server 2017 where replacing:

- a `CASE` statement that assigns a numerical value
- with a constant numerical value

slows down the query be a factor of 6+.

The rather complicated query has the general form of:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    ...
),
WITH CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT
        --conditions based on below
    FROM 
        (SELECT
            --various math,
            CASE 
                --statement assigning values to different runID combinations for samples with matching siteIDs and dates (due to the ON statement below)
                ELSE NULL
                ....
            END AS whichCombination
        FROM 
            CTE1 AS value1
        JOIN 
            CTE1 AS value2 ON (value1.siteID = value2.siteID, 
                               value1.date = value2.date, 
                               value1.sampleID <> value2.sampleID)
    ) AS combinations
    WHERE combinations.whichCombination IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT various data
FROM dataTable
LEFT JOIN 
    (stuff from CTE2) AS pairTable ON dataTable.sampleID = pairTable.sampleID
```

The `CASE` statement assigns a pair number to different combinations of rows from the self join.

This then is used to select only the combinations that I want.

However, when the `CASE` statement is replaced with: `1 AS whichCombination` (a constant value so no rows are assigned NULL) the query slows dramatically. This also occurs if `CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 1` is used.

This makes no sense to me as either way the values are:

- numerical
- not unique
- not an index

The only thing that is unique is that each combination of rows is a assigned a unique value.

Is SQL Server somehow using this as an index that speeds things up?

And how would I replicate this behavior without the CASE statement as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996194/11715606) says you cannot create indices for CTE's?

**EDIT:** Also of note is that the slowdown occurs only if main select statement (the last 5 lines) is included (i.e. if CTE2 is run as the main select statement instead of being a CTE)

---

Best, JD

Comment: Did you look at the plans and compare them? The fact that the constant is never null, but the case does allow NULLs most likely results in a different plan. See the estimated and actual number of rows passed along.

Comment: Ok I will look into that. So a different plan could be enacted just on the possibility of NULLs (even if no NULLs are assigned in the CASE statement)

Comment: Did any results from the original case statement end up with NULL? Also, was there a join condition on that last left join?

Comment: @Uueerdo, no they were always all integers. This is why I figured I would replace the CASE statement with a constant (I could not get ride of the variable altogether for other reasons). Yes there was a join condition which I added.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround would be spliting these CTE's to temp tables, then you could add indexes if needed.

Comment: There is NO SHAME in using temp tables.   +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also quite interested in the mechanism causing the slowdown. Any thoughts there?

Comment: @johnDanger you need to run both queries and compare query plan, see where the most expensive parts are and understand it what causes it.